# show map $\Delta:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow{\mathcal{F}}$ is bijective

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}:=\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}|f$ is right c.t.s, non-decreasing and $f(0)=0\}$

Let $\mathcal{M}:=\{\mu:(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})\rightarrow{[0,\infty)}|\mu{([a,b])}<\infty{}$ for all $a\lt{}b\in{\mathbb{R}}\}$

want to show the map $\Delta$ that maps a function $f\in{}\mathcal{F}$ to the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $\lambda_f{}\in{}\mathcal{M}$ is bijective, and construct a suitable two sided inverse.

I have shown the injective case but don't understand how show its surjective.

note: we say $\lambda_f((a,b])=f(b)-f(a)$.

I have tried taking some $\mu\in\mathcal{M}$. And saying it must equal some $\lambda_f$ for some $f$.

Also any hints about constructing the inverse would be appreciated.

Comment: If $\mu$ is such a measure, then $f(x) = \mu((0,x])$ is such a function such that $\mu = \lambda_f$. Though, I believe there are some assumptions missing. If I'm not mistaken, the right continuity of $f$ holds iff there are no singletons $\{x\}$ with $\mu(\{ x\})  > 0$, so this will need to be an additional requirement for $\mathcal M$ (or perhaps this is buried somewhere in the definition you are using for Borel measures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $\lambda\in\mathcal{M}$, let $f(x)=\lambda((0,x])$, then $f$ is increasing, $f(0)=0$ and right-continuous, and this map and the map $f\rightarrow\lambda_{f}$ are inverse to each other.